# Internal as well as external partition of (regular) graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a simple finite undirected graph. Let $\{V_1,V_2\}$ be a partition of its vertex set; that is, $V_1\cup V_2=V(G)$ and $V_1\cap V_2=\emptyset$. The partition $\{V_1,V_2\}$ is said to be an *internal partition* if every vertex has at least as many neighbours in its own part than in the other part. The partition $\{V_1,V_2\}$ is said to be an *external partition* if every vertex has at most as many neighbours in its own part than in the other part.

It is known that $G$ always has an external partition. The situation is more diverse for internal partitions (eg: see [1]). There are many unresolved problems and conjectures on internal partitions even when the input graph is even regular.

**Is partitions that are both internal and external studied in the literature?**
(that is, a partition $\{V_1,V_2\}$ such that every vertex has the same number of neighbors in its own part as in the other part).

If it matters, I am more interested in even regular graph (esp. 4-regular graphs) and in partition into equal-sized parts (i.e. $|V_1|=|V_2|$).

[1] *Ban, Amir; Linial, Nati*, [**Internal partitions of regular graphs**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/jgt.21909), J. Graph Theory 83, No. 1, 5-18 (2016). [ZBL1346.05223](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1346.05223).